# AngularJS convert unicode html ng-repeat

Tags: jquery, angularjs, unicode, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-bind-html

I have an issue with AngularJS. I have this code in my template to display a list of users:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item class="item-avatar" ng-repeat="x in filtered = ( users | filter:query)" href="#/user/{{x.ID}}">
    <img src="http://m.myapp2go.de/ionic/todo/www/img/ionic.png" />
    <h2>{{x.Name1}}</h2>
    <p>
      {{x.Name2}} - ({{x.Phone}})
    </p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I get my data in a $http.get-request. JSON is unicoded, e.g.: "Name1":"• RS's •"

```
{"items":[{"ID":"10033","UserID":"RSC","Passwort":"66676e6567313233","Name1":"&bull; RS&#039;s &bull;","Name2":"Schumacher","NameZusatz":"RSC", ......
},
```

How can i display Name1 `{{x.Name1}}` in the right way in my template?
In my controller i have a function which is decoding a string in the correct way using jquery.

```
$scope.decodeHTML = function(html_code) {
    if (html_code) {
      return $('<div />').html(html_code).text();
    } else {
      return '';
    }
};
```

Do i have to change the `$scope-data` with the converted string or are there other possibilities? I tried everything with `ng-bind-html="expression"` but no success.

Comment: If i  understood your question properly , u need to escape the $scope-data object using  $sce (Strict Contextual Escaping) dependency $sce.trustAsHtml can be used for this , please refer this  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce  hope it helps

Comment: $sce.trustAsHtml works fine, but how can i change the contents of my $scope? $scope is filled with 'code' $scope.users = response.items'code'  in $http.get-function. This is a example of the first JSON-element:

{"items":[{"ID":"10033","UserID":"RSC","Passwort":"66676e6567313233","Name1":"&bull; RS&#039;s &bull;","Name2":"Schumann","NameZusatz":"RSC" ...,}

Comment: glad it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution:

```
  // decode unicoded html
$scope.decodeHTML = function(x){
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(x);
    };
```

In my template :

```
<h2 ng-bind-html="decodeHTML(x.Name1)"></h2>
```

That's it.